# How to stop current execution process in ESS when C-c C-c is unresponsive?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I'm handling a datatable with a big amount of text in its fields and when, by mistake, I call a command that starts to print it causes R to freeze or to slowly print everything, I then have to kill emacs and resetup all my windows and buffers. This because during the printing process the command `C-c C-c` is unresponsive.

Do you knnow how to proceed to handle this without killing the whole working setup ?

Comment: Have you tried C-g `keyboard-quit` ?

Answer (score 3):

You could kill just the ess process with something like,

```
(defun ess-abort ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-process (ess-get-process)))
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-a") 'ess-abort)
(define-key inferior-ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-a") 'ess-abort)
```

eg, in R repl,

```
library(ggplot2)
toString(diamonds)
```

followed by `C-c C-a`.  Haven't tried it on Windows however.

Comment: replacing "kill-process" by "interrupt-process" in the code above (pasted into the .emacs file) allows you to keep your R session open and with it all  the data you already generated

Comment: thanks good to know, I think there was some recent effort to fix this problem in ESS